# image not showing full screen in iphone4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an image at the center of the view in Storyboard. On iphone 5 it shows fullscreen, but on iphone 4 (I use a different image on iphone 4 - set programmatically), it shows white space at the top.

How do I remove the white space at the top on iphone 4?

Here's the code:

```
UIImage * img;

if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
    img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"page1"];
} else {
    img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ip4_page1"];
}

[self.centerImage setImage: img];
[self.centerImage setFrame: self.view.frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the screen aspect ratio. You can change the `UIImageView` way of displaying an image like this:

```
self.yourImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

That way the image will expand maintaining its aspect. You can try with other configurations to achieve different results.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the image is indeed filling your whole screen (which you can test by giving it a background color), you need to make sure that the fill mode is correct.

```
self.centerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill
// or
self.centerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
```

The first option will show all of the image, so it might be distorted.
The second option will avoid distortion, but might cut off top/bottom or left/right edges.

Answer (score -1):

Set your `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

```
self.centerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

You could also set your `UIImageView`'s background color to `clear` if increasing the images size to fill the view does not meet your needs.

```
self.centerImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```